# Variation of a complex measure and Hahn decomposition of the real and imaginary parts

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ is a complex measure on $(X,\mathscr{A})$. Let $\mu_1,\mu_2$ be the real and imaginary parts of $\mu$ respectively. If $(P_1,N_1)$ is a Hahn decomposition of $\mu_1$ and $(P_2,N_2)$ is a Hahn decomposition of $\mu_2$. Is it then true that
\begin{equation}
|\mu|(A)=\left(\mu_1(A\cap P_1\cap P_2)^2+\mu_2(A\cap P_1\cap P_2)^2\right)^{1/2}+\left(\mu_1(A\cap P_1\cap N_2)^2+\mu_2(A\cap P_1\cap N_2)^2\right)^{1/2}+
\left(\mu_1(A\cap N_1\cap P_2)^2+\mu_2(A\cap N_1\cap P_2)^2\right)^{1/2}+\left(\mu_1(A\cap N_1\cap N_2)^2+\mu_2(A\cap N_1\cap N_2)^2\right)^{1/2}
\end{equation}
holds for every $A\in\mathscr{A}$?

My gut feeling is yes (as I came up with the expression myself), but I have no idea whether that feeling is correct or how to prove it.

Edit: I suppose the previous expression could be written shorter as
\begin{equation}
|\mu|(A)=|\mu(A\cap P_1\cap P_2)|+|\mu(A\cap P_1\cap N_2)|+|\mu(A\cap N_1\cap P_2)|+|\mu(A\cap N_1\cap N_2)|.
\end{equation}
Which is true if $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^4=\{A\cap P_1\cap P_2,A\cap P_1\cap N_2,A\cap N_1\cap P_2,A\cap N_1\cap N_2\}$ are those subsets $\mathscr{A}$-measurable subsets of $A$ which maximize $\sum_{k=1}^m |\mu(B_k)|$ where $\{B_k\}_{k=1}^m$ are finite, disjoint, disjoint, $\mathscr{A}$-measurable subsets of $A$ such that $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^m B_k$. That feels right, but I am not completely sure.

Edit 2: I've been told that additional context is needed. I am self-studying from the second edition of Donald L. Cohn's *Measure Theory* and came up with this expression when trying to prove Proposition 4.2.5.
The proposition states:

*Suppose $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ is a measure space, that $f\in\mathscr{L}^1(X,\mathscr{A},\mu,\mathbb{R}$) or $f\in\mathscr{L}^1(X,\mathscr{A},\mu,\mathbb{C})$, and that $\nu$ is the finite signed or complex measure defined by $\nu(A)=\int_Af\,d\mu$. Then $|\nu|(A)=\int_A|f|\,d\mu$ holds for every $A\in\mathscr{A}$.*

I believe that I managed to prove the case where $f$ is real valued (and hence $\nu$ a finite signed measure) by considering a Hahn decomposition of $\nu$. I wanted to try something similar for the complex case, and came up with the above expressions. If it is of any value for the context this is my proof for the signed case:

Let $(P,N)$ be a Hahn decomposition of $\nu$. Since $f$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable $(\{x\in X: f>0\}\cap N),(\{x\in X: f<0\}\cap P)\in\mathscr{A}$, call those two sets $B,C$ respectively. Since $B\subseteq N$ it must be that $\nu(B)\leq0$, but $f(x)>0$ for every $x\in B$, thus it must be that $\mu(B)=0$. Similarly $\mu(C)=0$. Let $N'=(N\setminus B)\cup C$ and $P'=(P\setminus C)\cup B$, then $(P',N')$ is also a Hahn decomposition of $\nu$ and
\begin{equation}
f^+=\begin{cases}
f(x), &x\in P'\\
0,  &x\notin P'
\end{cases},
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
f^-=\begin{cases}
-f(x), &x\in N'\\
0,  &x\notin N'
\end{cases}.
\end{equation}

Let $A\in\mathscr{A}$, then the relations
\begin{equation}
|\nu|(A)=\nu(A\cap P')-\nu(A\cap N')=\int_A f^++f^- \, d\mu=\int_A |f|\,d\mu
\end{equation}
establishes the sought equality.

If anyone wishes to look at the definitions I use, I am making myself a cheat-sheet here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/rztrkjkkstfd